# How to get the Keyboard curser focus to edit the label text, when we double click on CheckboxTreeViewer selected item

Tags: java, jface, treeviewer

```
public class MyLabelProvider extends LabelProvider {

    @Override
    public Image getImage(Object element) {
        return createImage(imagePath);
    }

    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        return MessageFormat.format((String)element); // CheckBOxTreeViewer, AA, BBB //and etc.
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

}


public class MyContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider, IViewerListener {

    private CheckboxTreeViewer viewer;
  @Override
    public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object NewInput) {

    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
    }
    @Override
    public Object getParent(Object element) {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
    }
    @Override
    public void refreshOnlyContent(Object element) {
    }
    @Override
    public void refreshOnlyLabels() {
    }
    @Override
    public void refreshEverything(Object element) {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }
}


public class MyClass {

@PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(Composite composite) {

CheckboxTreeViewer   treeViewer = new CheckboxTreeViewer(Composite);

MyContentProvider contentProvider = new MyContentProvider ();

treeViewer.setContentProvider(contentProvider);

IViewerListener  viewerListener = contentProvider;

treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new MyLabelProvider ());

treeViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {

 @Override
public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {

      //editor cursor focus code
  }
});

}
}
```

How to edit `CheckboxTreeViewer` label text.

In this project example label texts are `CheckBOxTreeViewer`, AA, BBB and etc.

How to get the Keyboard cursor focus inorder to edit the label text, when we double click on `CheckboxTreeViewer` item.
[CheckboxTreeViewer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvO7j.png)

Comment: You need to use `EditingSupport` read something like [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html) (editing support applies to trees as well as tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edition is not like in AWT/Swing.

you need to use on the treeViewer:

- `setColumnProperties()` which names the column for edition. By default the tree has only one column, so you can use an array of only one element)
- `setCellEditors()` which indicates how you edit the value(s) (text,
  combo, ...)
- `setCellModifier()` which makes the connection between the row object,
  and the editor (convert value, indicates whether the value is
  editable, ...)

If you want the edition on double click:

```
TreeViewerEditor.create(treeViewer, new ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy(treeViewer){
    protected boolean isEditorActivationEvent(ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent event) {  
        return event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_DOUBLE_CLICK_SELECTION;
    }
```

You can check this very interesting article as well: http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/in-place-editing-in-eclipse-treeviewer/